# VS2022 and Premake: Add parallel build for new rule

Tags: visual-studio-2022, premake

I have created a premake script to insert my C/C++ files and also ".asm" files.

I created a rule to compile the ".asm" files with FASM.

Everything works as expected, except that the ".asm" files are not built using Parallel build. The C/C++ files are built in parallel (I set the parallel option for C)

Is there any way to specify build in parallel for my FASM rule?

I see that if I manually select a ".asm" in the Solution explorer and click on "Properties", I can change it to "Item Type -> Custom Build" and there is a option "Build in Parallel". But this option is not present when I select my "FASM custom" item type (generated by premake)

Is it possible to do it in Premake or another possible workaround? Like manually changing the generated custom rules files by Premake?

Thanks!

Comment: providing premake script might help. But as far as I know, there are no specific options in premake for parallell build in rules.

Comment: Created https://github.com/Jarod42/premake-core/tree/vs2010_CustomBuild_BuildInParallel which enables parallel build for customBuild (with `flags { "MultiProcessorCompile" }`)

Comment: @Jarod42, Thanks a lot for that feature! My bad for asking this, but is there any compiled Windows release to try that feature?

Comment: There are artefacts disponible in [action](https://github.com/Jarod42/premake-core/actions/runs/4646061398) for some (limited) time.

Comment: Using github to ask for the feature or help might be appropriate.

Comment: @Jarod42. Thanks a lot! I got the new binary from the artifacts section. I have put the new flag under the filter section in solution but I don't get parallel compilation for my rule "FasmCustomRule". Is the new flag only available for the type "Custom Build" but not if I create a new rule?

Comment: I also put the new flags under the "project" section and under the filter section, but nothing. I'm using VS2022

Comment: My fix was for CustomBuild, it seems custom rule doesn't use same code path. I will investigate further.